# How to use pollEnrich in camel k?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I am relative new with camel-k.
I have to rewrite a working route to camel k using DSL.

Context:

- the route reads from a queue
- input is a json with 2 fields: field1, field2
- I have to read a XML file and replace 2 values: one with field1, another with a property read from file
- then I have to call a SOAP service using the XML described above

I managed to parse the JSON
I think I have to use the pollEnrich to read the file, but I can't
Then, it's not clear what todo.
Could you help?

`poolEnrich:

- constant:

  - simple: file:////

-to:
uri: bean:globalProp?method=setProperty('name', ${body})

-beans:
-name: golabProp
type: java.util.Properties`

Comment: I think this is not specific to Camel K (which only takes care of the deployment part). You can have a look at some example out there, ie https://access.redhat.com/documentation/es-es/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/msgtran